# VB Code - Multiple Remote SSH connections to same server

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, openssh, vbcodeprovider

Is it possible to connect several users via openSSH to the same VM so that everyone can access VB Code on the same VM machine and run scripts? thrue the local VB Code

If so, how do I do this?